# WCF -> Commit Derived Objects with a a Basic Call

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, communication, servicehost

I've this WCf Interface definition

```
public interface IDataToMfcV2
{       
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    SecurityAnswerDTO CommitDTOs(string sessionId, BasicDTO[] basicDto);        
}
```

and now I have different Objects which derive from BasicDTO! Now I want to know, is it Possible to send a List of derived Objects to this call?

Because I got this exception:

> The message with Action 'X' cannot be processed at the receiver, due
>   to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be
>   because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between
>   sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender
>   and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same
>   contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g.
>   Message, Transport, None).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my fault! I connected to a completly wrong URI!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute to the service interface for all derived classes which you are planning to send and receive using the service.

e.g.

```
public class X : BasicDTO
public class Y : BasicDTO

[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(X))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Y))]
public interface IDataToMfcV2
{       
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    SecurityAnswerDTO CommitDTOs(string sessionId, BasicDTO[] basicDto);        
}
```

Comment: I've done this via the 
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(IDataToMfcV2KnownTypes))]
Attribute.


And the GetKnowTypes method, returns the Types I tryed to sumbit (i've debugged it). But I got this error...